# getMonth() reacting weird

Tags: lightning-web-components, date

I am trying to create an array of the months between the start date and end date. So far I am ok with it BUT I do have a weird case where when I am looking at my start date and using the getMonth(), if my start date is the first of the month, it returns the previous month. example:

`this.date1 = new Date(this.opportunity.data.fields.Start_Date__c.value)`; //Set to 2021-02-01, will return 0

`this.date1 = new Date(this.opportunity.data.fields.Start_Date__c.value);` //Set to 2021-02-02, will return 1

Did you guys experienced that in the past? How can I fix that? I thought it was due to UTC but both my computer and Salesforce settings are EST.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you check what the value for `this.opportunity.data.fields.Start_Date__c.value` actually is?
If it's a string, what is its exact format?
Additionally, try adding this after your date assignment and check what your Date instance actually interpreted the input as: `console.log(this.date1.toISOString());`
It should look something like this: `"2021-02-02T00:00:00.000Z"`

Comment: I am guessing it is because of UTC as you mentioned. To check this move your user timezone to PST as well as your system timezone and see if it is correct.

Comment: Sure I can give a try, right now they are all Est. Will give a try thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Date.prototype.getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

> The getMonth() method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year).

Sample [playground](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/VoKw33rCE2X2E5A3SZvY)

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-input type="date" label="Enter a date" onchange={handleDate}>
    </lightning-input>
    <p> Selected date: {selDate} </p>
    <p> Get Month: {monthVal} </p>

</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {

  monthVal;
  selDate;

  handleDate(event){
    let dt = event.target.value;
    this.selDate = dt;
    this.monthVal = new Date(dt).getMonth();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not give enough details. Let me clarify. The date is coming from the date field (date picker) so the first is actually Feb 1 and the second is Feb 2. The problem is both should return the value 1 for the month of Feb but Feb 1 return 0 for the month of January. This is very strange!

Comment: Oh ok. But see edited answer, couldn't reproduce this issue on the playground. Are you sure the first date is February ?

Comment: more than sure, I am using a date picker. when I click on feb 3 is working an so on. only the first day of each month return the value of the previous month

Comment: Could you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/334114/edit) your question to provide more details on your code? which API version is your LWC ?